export restclient request to cUrl
I qm using restclient to call a webapi, but need to have its cUrl equivalent.
var curl = httpClient.GenerateCurlInString(httpRequestMessage);

I need something like  this:
var curl = httpClient.GenerateCurlInString(httpRequestMessage);


you question is not clear both the code is same

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
